# Selenium WebDriver first Java example to set up

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver

I created pom.xml and an example file Selenium2Example.java to set up Maven.
I followed the instructions on here http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#chrome-driver

But I am getting the error **"Selection does not contain a main type"** on running Selenium2Example.java as Java Application.

Here is the pom.xml I am using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" >
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>MySel20Proj</groupId>
        <artifactId>MySel20Proj</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
                <version>2.25.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.opera</groupId>
                <artifactId>operadriver</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.opera</groupId>
                    <artifactId>operadriver</artifactId>
                    <version>0.16</version>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                            <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Here is the Selenium2Example.java I am using:

```
package org.openqa.selenium.example;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Selenium2Example  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a new instance of the Chrome driver
        // Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface, 
        // not the implementation.
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        // And now use this to visit Google
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        // Alternatively the same thing can be done like this
        // driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com");
        // Find the text input element by its name
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

        // Enter something to search for
        element.sendKeys("Cheese!");
        // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element
        element.submit();

        // Check the title of the page
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());

        // Google's search is rendered dynamically with JavaScript.
        // Wait for the page to load, timeout after 10 seconds
        (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
                return d.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith("cheese!");
            }
        });
        // Should see: "cheese! - Google Search"
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());        
        //Close the browser
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

On running it gives the following error 
Run as -> Run config -> (selecting Selenium2Example.java under TestNG

The error is

```
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot find class in classpath: Selenium2Example
    at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.loadClass(XmlClass.java:76)
    at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.init(XmlClass.java:68)
    at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.<init>(XmlClass.java:54)
    at org.testng.xml.TestNGContentHandler.startElement(TestNGContentHandler.java:542)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:506)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:766)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1302)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2715)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:488)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:302)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:17)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:10)
    at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:172)
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:310)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:88)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you made the right decision (from my point) to use Maven, Java and WebDriver ;)

What you've done looks like you've selected the wrong package or file to run!

That's not a problem of Selenium, it's a problem of your run configuration, your IDE!

I guess you use Eclipse?

Try to right-click the file you want to run -> run as -> Java Application

That should fix your Problem...

If you want to do some testing with Selenium WebDriver, don't forget to choose a Testing- Framework. I would recommend JUnit or even better TestNG...

Comment: "Selection does not contain a main type" and your TestNG error are different types of errors.... if you run it with a main you don't need TestNG- if you run it with TestNG you have to remove the main and annotate it with @Test. Use this [Manual](http://testng.org/doc/selenium.html)

Comment: TestNG is better than JUnit... I think

Comment: TestNG is no longer better than JUnit. As of JUnit 4.11, it also does Parameterized tests.   You can use Ant (via Maven) or Gradle to generate reports.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with the java code. Pl check the installation of the correct driver.. Try by changing the chrome driver with the firefox driver.